# Is there an equivalent for \gdesc in mysql?

Tags: mysql-cli

In postgres, whenever I want to print a description of a query, I could add `\gdesc` as follows:

```
# select 1 as num \gdesc
 Column |  Type   
--------+---------
 num    | integer
(1 row)
```

I was wondering if there's an equivalent in MySQL (or in any other relational database).

I'm aware of `DESCRIBE Table`, but I'm looking to describe a query, not a table.

Comment: It is a command-line feature and has nothing to do with SQL. Each DBMS has its own cli and, well, it's a very specific use case (generally there's some IDE that depicts datatypes in UI)

Comment: @astentx I'm aware of that it's a CLI command, but I wasn't sure how to exactly call it. My question was if there's an equivalent in some way in other DBMS

Comment: The datatypes system in MySQL is soft, so trying to determine the data type of a column precisely doesn't make sense.